statsmodel logit singular matrix
I am new in machine learning and I need an advice: I am predicting spam calls based on the call details records (CDR) of an Internet-based PBX. The fact is that I obtain singular matrices during regression even if VIF is low (less than 4) for my 11 estimators, and p-value is also low.
These are the steps that I've done:

Test all combinations of the estimators in logistic regression, and discarding the combinations that don't allow the regression to converge, or the combinations that result in singular matrices.
For every combinations, I've calculated accuracy, p-value and VIF.
I have selected one of the combinations with higher accuracy, and then I've removed, one by one, the variables with VIF higher than 5, always recalculating the regression before removing the next one, and I have obtained a set of estimators having VIF less than 4. I've considered p-values for variable removal as well.
For the selected combination I have calculated the correlation matrix, which shows poorly correlated estimators (less than 0.4).
At this point collinearity has been greatly reduced, but if I run the regression against a new set of data, depending on the new set I might get a singular matrix.
Cross-validation also works only in specific cases, but in general throws the singular matrix error.
The training dataset is made of 32,375 records and 11 max predictors (reduced to 5-6 to accomodate for VIF and p-values useful ranges). The number of "n" is roughly 11,800 and the number of "y" is 18,200.
I have a datetime variable that marks every call and that shows very high VIF (so this variable is the first I've removed). Not sure why, but before removing it I've tried to consider groups of days instead of timestamps, as I thought that timestamps could be too selective and CDRs usually span 3-4 days. It didn't make any difference.
I've tried to use Lasso, but I've got the same result (singular matrix from time to time depending on the new set of data).

I am not sure if 30K records is a low number for this sort of problem, and I need much more to get a stable model, or if there is something else I miss. Do anyone has any suggestions?
